# Spring security authentication via URL: handle bad token

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security's ability to auto login by unauthenticated request, when it looks at request url and determines whether user is using correct token or no, then do auto login on success and show message on failure:

```
public class LinkRememberMeService implements RememberMeServices, LogoutHandler
{
    @Autowired
    private UserAccountProvider userAccountProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication autoLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {
        //if ok - return authentication object
        //if not ok - retun null then spring redirects to default intercept-url
        //but instead of retuning null i need to render view with error message for this case
    }
    .....
}
```

`autoLogin` can return authentication object or null, when object is returned (token is ok) user is automatically logged in, that's fine. However in case of bad token you have only one option to return null, and Spring redirects to default entry url (ex. '/login').

In case of bad token i want to either render thymeleaf template or redirect to failure url, but i can't find a way to make it work.

Comment: Are you looking at implementing a standard failure page or message on remember me? http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html

Comment: i want to avoid standard failure page on bad token, and show custom failure page.